# No such table error when try to use database in Android project

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating database tables to my android project and the following is the helper class. I am able to create the database, when I try to get the data from the method getSettings() it is showing an error saying that no such table 'Settings'.

But I created the table in onCreate method. After that I debug and found that OnCreate method is not calling. Here is my code:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{ 
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
//destination path (location) of our database on device 
private static String DB_PATH = "";  
private static String DB_NAME ="testDatabase";// Database name 
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
private final Context mContext; 

private final String SETTINGS_TABLE = "settings";
private final String SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private final String SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID = "profileId";

private final String SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + SETTINGS_TABLE
        + "(" + SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID + " varchar(100), );";
private final int SETTINGS_ID = 1;
   public DataBaseHelper(Context context)  
   { 
     super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version 
     DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; 
     this.mContext = context; 
  }    

 public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
 { 
   //If database not exists copy it from the assets 

boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
if(!mDataBaseExist) 
{ 
    this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    this.close(); 
    try  
    { 
        //Copy the database from assests 
        copyDataBase(); 
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
    }  
    catch (IOException mIOException)  
    { 
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
    } 
} 
} 
//Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name 
private boolean checkDataBase() 
{ 
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
    return dbFile.exists(); 
} 

//Copy the database from assets 
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int mLength; 
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
    { 
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
    } 
    mOutput.flush(); 
    mOutput.close(); 
    mInput.close(); 
} 

//Open the database, so we can query it 
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
{ 
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
    mDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
    return mDataBase != null; 
} 

@Override 
public synchronized void close()  
{ 
    if(mDataBase != null) 
        mDataBase.close(); 
    super.close(); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDataBase = db;
    
    System.out.println("Oncreate table");
    try {
        db.execSQL(SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE);
        InsertSettingsData();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Success create SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private int InsertSettingsData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "InsertConfigInitialData");

    try {
        ContentValues resourceTable = new ContentValues();
        resourceTable.put(SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID, SETTINGS_ID);
        resourceTable.put(SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID,
                "123456");
        
        int resourceId = (int) mDataBase.insert(SETTINGS_TABLE, null,
                resourceTable);
        if (resourceId >= 0) {
            return resourceId;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "InsertConfigInitialData failed : " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return -1;
    
}
public boolean UpdateConfigData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "UpdateConfigData");
    try {
        String condition = SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID + "=" + SETTINGS_ID;

        ContentValues resourceTable = new ContentValues();
        resourceTable.put(SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID,
                "34567");

        int totalUpdated = mDataBase.update(SETTINGS_TABLE,
                resourceTable, condition, null);
        if (totalUpdated > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "UpdateConfigData failed, no records updated");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateConfigData failed : " + e.toString());
    }
    return false;
}

public SettingsObject getSettings() {
    Log.d(TAG, "LoadConfigs");
    SettingsObject settings = new SettingsObject();
    String condition = SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID + "=" + SETTINGS_ID;

    try {
        Cursor cursor = mDataBase.query(SETTINGS_TABLE, null,
                condition, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            SettingsObject.setProfile_id(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID)));

            cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "LoadConfigs failed : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return settings;
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
} 

}
```

from my activity class I am calling like this,

```
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
     
    try {
     
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
     
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
     
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
     
    }
     
    try 
    {
     
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
     
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
     
    throw sqle;
     
    }
    
    SettingsObject object = myDbHelper.getSettings();
    
    System.out.println("settings profile Id" + object.getProfile_id());
```

### Edit

Can I call creating database tables in the following method?

```
       //Open the database, so we can query it 
     public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
     { 
       String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
       //Log.v("mPath", mPath); 
       mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,   SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
    //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS); 
    mDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
    mDataBase.execSQL(SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE);
    InsertSettingsData();
      return mDataBase != null; 
  }
```

Comment: How did you find the onCreate method didn't run? Have you kill the process and restart your application?

Comment: @JermaineXu, I uninstalled the application and re installed. Got the same problem

Comment: You updated code is useful, writing answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreate()` will not be called because the database already exists -- your code shows that you are copying the database from assets if it doesn't exist, so by the time you invoke SQLiteOpenHelper, it **does** exist and `onCreate()` is skipped. In your special case, you can not rely on SQLiteOpenHelper to dispatch the correct events, but rather, you need to copy from assets, then open and amend the schema all at once.

You'd want something like this:

```
boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
if(!mDataBaseExist) 
{ 
    try  
    { 
        //Copy the database from assests 
        copyDataBase(); 
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWriteableDatabase();
        db.execSQL( ...create ddl... );

    }  
    catch (IOException mIOException)  
    { 
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please check my edit1, and please let me know is that code good to go?

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra character `,` in your create table syntax. You need to remove that last character ( comma ) from your syntax,

your syntax,

```
private final String SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + SETTINGS_TABLE
        + "(" + SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID + " varchar(100), );";
```

Update it to

```
private final String SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " + SETTINGS_TABLE
        + "(" + SETTINGS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + SETTINGS_COLUMN_PROFILE_ID + " varchar(100) );";
```

Now your syntax is ready.

Comment: I think "create table if not exists" is better.

Comment: @Husker, thanks for the suggestion even though I am unable to create the table because, Oncreate method is not triggered. Can you please check this.

Comment: Change the System.out.println("Oncreate table") to Log.d(...), and check if the log will get printed. @ChandraSekhar

Comment: @JermaineXu, I tried with that too but no use. It doesn't called

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is onCreate not getting executed.

Actually, onCreate won't be called at all unless you call the getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase methods on your SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

or

```
myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

onCreate isn't called from its constructor, it's called by the Android framework when you try to access(read/write) your database.